# WSO2 APIUtil Error while creating axis configuration for tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API-Manager 3.0. When I browse to the DevPortal (before signing in) I can see the list of APIs.

But when I login (using my email as assigned by my organization's IAM team) I get a red pop-up message saying 'Error While Loading APIs':

[image]

The log file revels this message:

```
api-manager_1             | [2020-04-13 17:47:58,602]  INFO - PermissionUpdater Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
api-manager_1             | [2020-04-13 17:48:00,125] ERROR - APIUtil Error while creating axis configuration for tenant mydomain.com
api-manager_1             | java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while getting tenant activation status.
api-manager_1             |     at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
api-manager_1             |     at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantAxisConfiguration(TenantAxisUtils.java:104) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
api-manager_1             |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.loadTenantConfigBlockingMode_aroundBody372(APIUtil.java:6166) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
api-manager_1             |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.loadTenantConfigBlockingMode(APIUtil.java:6162) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
api-manager_1             |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.impl.WebAppAuthenticatorImpl.authenticate(WebAppAuthenticatorImpl.java:129) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util_6.5.349.jar:?]
api-manager_1             |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor.handleRequest(OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor.java:121) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util_6.5.349.jar:?]
api-manager_1             |     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor.handleMessage(OAuthAuthenticationInterceptor.java:66) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util_6.5.349.jar:?]
api-manager_1             |     at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
api-manager_1             |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
api-manager_1             |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
api-manager_1             |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
api-manager_1             |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
api-manager_1             |     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
```

(plus another 200 lines of trace-back)

When I login to the Publisher the page loads with a spinning icon that says "Loading Settings" and stays there forever:

[image]

Again the log file reveals the same message as above.

Note: Other users in my organization are able to login and view the APIs just fine. But they are not using an email address to authenticate. I am the only using an email address to authenticate.

Another Note: Our organization uses an IAM server for authentication.

Any suggestions on what to try next to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WSO2 servers, the username `john@tenant.com` represents the user `john` in `abc.com` tenant. Therefore, you email domain has been identified as a tenant domain. Try the below format for your username. It should work.

`john@gmail.com@tenant.com`

If you don't have multiple tenants, use `carbon.super` as the tenant. So your username should go like this.

`john@gmail.com@carbon.super`

Comment: Thanks @Bee, but I forgot to mention that the WSO2 login page is directed to my organization's IAM server for authentication. I tried your suggestions but they don't get past the  IAM server (i.e. I get  'login incorrect' msg).

Comment: It should be handled from that side then. In the login response which comes to APIM, the username should have the above format.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification, @Bee. I'll ask my IAM to format accordingly. I'll report back here.

Comment: In our case our company IAM team gets username from a read-only HR database and are not able to modify the contents. So although this is the correct answer we were not able to avail of it. Instead, our solution was to stop using email address as the login name.